# Android programming (Trying to download a file to system directory)

Tags: java, android

Dear stackOverflow members i have recently started a new project called "RootBox" and it is an app that needs "su" perms and i have successfully allowed the app "su" or "root" access and im trying to download and replace a system file in "/system/media and i have setup my downloader but the download progress dialog pops up and closes which im guessing is the result of the file not being able to written to the system directory and i have Re-mounted the system as r-w before starting the download an i have searched all over the internet and was unable to find help thats why i have come here.

This is the activity executing the download

```
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bootmation);
    startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDownload();
            RootTools.remount("/system/", "rw");
        }
    });
}

private void startDownload() {
    String url = "http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/430746/bootanimation.zip";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    int count;

try {

URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();

int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/system/media/bootanimation.zip");

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
return null;

}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
     Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
     mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URL u = new URL(fUrls[i]);
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
c.setDoOutput(true);
                            c.connect();
```

Comment: u can take InputStream input = c.getInputStream(); and write inputsteram to  destination folder it may resolve your problem....

Answer (score 3):

for this u have to allow in manifest for permission for writing as

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: yea i added internet perms but would it make a differnce if the destination file already existed

Comment: i am not getting u properly. try to explain more

Comment: ok im trying to download a file to the /system/media directory and the file im downloading to the media directory already exists in the media directory

Comment: aka trying to replace boot animation called "bootanimation" and the name of the file im downloading is called "bootanimation" so i was trying to get the downloaded file to replace the existing file

Comment: So in my case how would i put that into my code because im a little confused

Comment: is there an example of how to put that into use somewhere?